# python from custom module ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'activity'

Tags: python, centos

I use Python 3.6.8 on Centos8.
under /home/azkaban/python_codes/pyib/activity,I put dbconnect.py, **init**.py,  pickgoods.py,  randomrow.py these python files.

```
pyib
----setup.py
----activity
-------__init__.py
-------dbconnect.py 
-------pickgoods.py  
-------randomrow.py
```

in pickgoods.py

```
from activity import dbconnect, randomrow
...
dbconnect.methodname1()
...
randomrow.methodname2()
```

when I run 'python3 /home/azkaban/python_codes/pyib/activity/pickgoods.py' in Centos shell command,it fails.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azkaban/python_codes/pyib/activity/pickgoods.py", line 13, in <module>
    from activity import dbconnect, randomrow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'activity'
```

But in PyCharm on Windows10 ,it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `activity` be found by your code, you need to have folder *containing* the `activity/` in your `sys.path`. I suppose PyCharm adds "current directory" to `sys.path` automatically or does some other magical behind the scenes.

#### Your options

1. If you run `pickgoods.py` directly, the folder containing it is added to `sys.path` automatically. Therefore, this should work

```
import dbconnect, randomrow
```

<sup><sub>*This solution is a bit suboptimal, since it depends on the entry point script location on the filesystem. **If your project starts to have subfolders and multiple entry points, I really recommend solution 2.***</sub></sup>

2. You can create `setup.py` to *parent* folder of `activity/` with following contents

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(name='mypackage', packages=setuptools.find_packages())
```

and install the package in editable state with

```
python -m pip install -e <folder_with_setup.py>
```

3. You can add the *parent* folder of `activity/` to `sys.path` manually, with `sys.path.insert(0, folder_with_activity)`. <sup><sub>*I think this is more of a hack, so I would recommend #2 instead.*</sub></sup>

Comment: I've create setup.py to parent folder of activity, and run python3 -m pip install -e /home/azkaban/python_codes/pyib, then how can I run pickgoods.py ?